# Certain parts of meta are broken with HTTPS everywhere

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I recently started to use meta.
I noticed that for me certain parts of meta are not functioning as expected.
Since before the [rollover to HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time) there has been a number of issues e.g. [non-matching certificates](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3438/whats-wrong-with-https).
Some of them were related to the HTTPS everywhere browser extension.
This caused some users to [not be able to log in](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2655/i-cannot-log-into-meta-while-using-https-everywhere-in-firefox) although this was before the move to `*.meta`.
There was also [redirection issues](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3241/have-to-use-chromium-to-ask-questions-on-meta) since then which seem to [be fixed](https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/pull/9110).

I think it's excellent that SE has made the move to full HTTPS.
I also understand that [it's hard](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/#certificates-child-metas-metastackexchangecom) so it's great that all of the effort is being put in to transition fully.
There are a few kinks that are still not ironed out while using Firefox with HTTPS everywhere.

- The "Recent inbox messages" button at the top doesn't open the pop up menu. It just flashes briefly.
- The inline help above the question text box never loads fully, the loading animation loops indefinitely.
- Trying to insert an image doesn't work, clicking the button or pressing Ctrl+G just puts a grey overlay over the screen. Successive key presses just lead to darker grey overlays
- When trying to post a question a red pop up box is displayed with the message "An error occurred submitting the question.".
- The tag suggestions never load but can be input manually.

I am running an updated Arch GNU/Linux with Firefox 54.0.1 and HTTPS everywhere 5.2.9.
These issues were fixed by disabling the "Stack Exchange (partial)" rules, this is of course not a correct solution though.
I assume this can be fixed by a small change to the [HTTPS everywhere ruleset](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/atlas/domains/stackexchange.com.html).
The linked page has a bug report link but I don't know enough of the technical details to post a good report.
I hope this is something easily fixable so we can make this great site even better.

Comment: I don't see any of these with 5.2.20, so I assume it already got fixed. It's just "Stack Exchange", not "Stack Exchange (partial)" for me.

Comment: That's a big derp on my part! Thanks for pointing out my out of date extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Michael Horner points out in the comments these problems have been fixed in a more recent version of HTTPS everywhere.
My problem was that somehow I had turned off the auto updates of my Firefox extensions.

The solution is to **Keep your system up to date!**